# Wrap an object with borders without changing properties or flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to wrap an object when moused over in a border so that it is visible, however, this will be used in a WYSIWYG type editor so adding styles directly to the object would break it. I'd like to wrap it in a div and style that div without actually changing the flow of the page.

I thought to create a div then position it relative while creating four divs within it to act as borders and position:absolute so it would not change any flow.

HTML:

```
<div class="bigBox">
    <div class="innerBox">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="floatingBox">

</div>
```

JavaScript with Jquery

```
$("div").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<div class="displayWrapper" style="position:relative" ></div>')
    .parent()
    .append('<div class="displayNodes" style="height:1px;width:100%;position:absolute;background-color:#66f;left:0;top:0"> </div>')
    .append('<div class="displayNodes" style="width:100%;height:1px;position:absolute;background-color:#66f;left:0px;bottom:0px"></div>')
    .append('<div class="displayNodes" style="width:1px;height:100%;position:absolute;background-color:#66f;right:0;top:0"> </div>')
    .append('<div class="displayNodes" style="width:1px;height:100%;position:absolute;background-color:#66f;right:0;bottom:0" </div>')
     })
.mouseout(function()
          {
              $(".displayNodes").remove();
              $(this).unwrap();
          });
```

and my CSS

```
.bigBox
{
    height:300px;
    position:relative; 
    background-color:black;
}
.innerBox
{
    height:25px;
    width:300px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;    
    right:4px;
    top:15px;
}

.floatingBox
{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:red;
    top:400px;
}
```

I set up a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94Nrb/3/

This method works great for normally positioned boxes, however, when the object is absolute or relative it messes things up since it's parent is moving, anyone have any ideas on this?

**Edit:** I had a slight mistake with the fiddle, updated to what it should be as version 3 http://jsfiddle.net/94Nrb/3/

Comment: did you try to set the lef and top, using the this(wrapped div) reference?

Comment: @fmodos if I understand what your recommending, that's what I did, I'm appending those fake borders to the parent object which is set to relative so when I set the absolutes on them, they are positioned absolutely within that div.

Comment: yes, but when the element is absolute, you will need to set the position of the parent based in its location

Comment: @fmodos I do have left(or right) and top(or bottom) set for all absolute elements.